# Postgres DISTINCT ON with index still sorts data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

A table with ~15 million rows.

Columns key, key2, timestamp.

Index on key, timestamp DESC NULLS LAST

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key) key, key2 FROM demo WHERE key IN (123, 443, 553)
```

'key' is not unique and there can be multiple duplicates of it.

I would have thought that a index with sorting would already be enough, yet explain still shows it - even if i specify GROUP BY - it's still there.

EXPLAIN:
uses correct index -> bitmap heap scan -> sort -> unique

It is quite costly to have it sort the massive table before getting unique values.

Did i create index in a wrong way?

Comment: `WHERE key IN (123)` : that is exactly one value. Which is always distinct.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Yes, i did miss a piece of information, it is not unique. I will update the post.